# Magento API order id vs. increment id

Tags: php, magento

I've found that there are two different properties of the order in Magento API available.

order_id and order_increment_id. For sample order they can be something like order_increment_id=100000080 and order_id=81.

The Question Is: What is the difference between them? How they are considered to be used? In the web store UI I see that my order has "Order #" = 100000080. What is order_id property for?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've been working with magento API for almost a year now and can assure you that the only ID you need to use is the order_increment_id. It is used as the main ID in the order.info call. The same is true for the invoice and shipment APIs - they also use the appropriate increment id as the main one.

The order_id, which I believe is the same as entity_id, is the primary key in the sales_order table used to join all the eav tables together. It is used internally in magento, but working with the API you needn't worry about it.

Comment: This is true for the SOAP api. If you are using the REST api, it wants the entity id, not the increment id. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/Resources/Orders/sales_orders.html

Comment: Answer is not correct for Magento 2.1. Really Magento 2.1 uses `entity_id` for soap calls

Comment: As mentioned elsewhere, if you are getting salesOrderShipments, you need to filter by the order_id, not the increment_id. In our system we store both because both are needed.

Answer (score 4):

I guess order_increment_id is used for displaying to the customer, and the order_id is for internal use. People find low order ids strange, they are used to seeing 10 digits or so when looking at order ids.

Answer (score 1):

What silvo has said is true and thats why there is method called getLastRealOrderId();

Answer (score 1):

What Silvo says is correct however there are some circumstances where the order_id is referenced in the API and is the only reference you have to get back to the order.

For example if you generated a list of SalesOrderInvoices or SalesOrderShipments then the reference back to the order, from the objects in the list, is given as the order_id, not the order_increment_id. Whilst you can get the SalesOrderEntity from the order_increment_id directly through a SalesOrderInfoRequest you will need to search for that order_id by using a SalesOrderListRequest with a filter on "order_id".

Answer (score 0):

For magento 2.1 (pehaps behaviour not the same for other versions ?!) you should use entity_id. I checked it on for SOAP API. Sometimes `entityId` looks like `incrementId` and this can lead to missunderstanding.

For example

- i try to call `SalesOrderRepositoryV1GetList` with parameter `id=275`
- received order has `<entityId>275</entityId>
  <incrementId>000000276</incrementId>`
- i try to call `SalesOrderRepositoryV1GetList` with parameter
  `id=000000276`
- received order has `<entityId>276</entityId>
  <incrementId>000000277</incrementId>`

In UI you will see `000000277` for `275`  and `000000276` for `276`